# Libgdx make scrollPane don't need a click interaction for starting scroll

Tags: java, libgdx, scrollpane

I'm trying to make a scroll pane that scrolls when the mouse is over, like web scroll panes, but for starting scroll I need to click the scroll pane, also for stopping scrolling I need to click outside it, anyone knows how to make work the scroll whitout clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the stage's scroll focus to the pane when you want the mouse wheel scrolling to work.